# Excel 2007 freezes hangs when I enter an email address

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, email, microsoft-excel-2007, freeze

I don't know how this started. But anytime I enter an email address, excel freezes. It never responds no matter what option I choose.
I have tried it with one cell and nothing else. I have tried it in safe mode and still freezes. Once excel realizes the cell is an email hyperlink, it freezes. I don't necessarily have to finish the email, just putting the @ symbol and hitting tab or enter will freeze it.

I'm not sure what else to share. Office 2007 Windows 7.

Comment: [How to install the individual 2007 Office features or to repair the installed 2007 Office programs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924611)

Comment: Are you using any plugins? It could be worth seeing if it freezes when you [start Excel in safe mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/work-with-office-safe-modes-HP010354300.aspx)

Comment: I've already tried safe mode, no go.